# Both request.json and request.get_json() fail in Flask 0.12.2 for windows

Tags: python, json, flask

I installed flask and wrote this basic code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/dashboard/create', methods=['POST'])
def build_dashboard():

    if "application/json" not in request.headers["Content-Type"]:
         abort(400)

    print('test1', file=sys.stderr)
    json_data = request.get_json()
    print("test2", file=sys.stderr)
    dashboard_data = {}
    return dashboard_data, 201
```

Then, I used curl to send a json request like this

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:5000/api/dashboard/create
```

The output I see is 
`test1
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2017 23:39:29] "POST /api/dashboard/create HTTP/1.1" 400`

So the call to request.get_json() causes an error or something.

- I tried also calling request.json but I got the same result (I've saw some 
  questions here regarding a similar issue, but always request.json or 
  request.get_json() seemed to work for people.
- When I printed request.is_json I got True
- I'm using flask 0.12.2 for windows, which should be the newest version I think.

Any idea what's happening?
Thanks a lot :)

edit:

Pdb step debugging before the call to request.get_json()

```
> c:\users\john\desktop\lively-backend\main.py(16)build_dashboard()
   -> json_data = request.get_json()
(Pdb) n
BadRequest: <BadRequ...Request'>
> c:\users\john\desktop\lively-backend\main.py(16)build_dashboard()
-> json_data = request.get_json()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\users\john\desktop\lively-backend\main.py(16)build_dashboard()->None
-> json_data = request.get_json()
(Pdb) n
BadRequest: <BadRequ...Request'>
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1598)dispatch_request()
-> return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1598)dispatch_request()->None
-> return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
(Pdb) n
BadRequest: <BadRequ...Request'>
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1612)full_dispatch_request()
-> rv = self.dispatch_request()
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1613)full_dispatch_request()
-> except Exception as e:
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1614)full_dispatch_request()
-> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1615)full_dispatch_request()
-> return self.finalize_request(rv)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1615)full_dispatch_request()-><Respons...REQUEST]>
-> return self.finalize_request(rv)
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1989)wsgi_app()
-> return response(environ, start_response)
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1991)wsgi_app()
-> if self.should_ignore_error(error):
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1993)wsgi_app()
-> ctx.auto_pop(error)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1993)wsgi_app()-><werkzeu...04467B38>
-> ctx.auto_pop(error)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12.2-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py(1997)__call__()-><werkzeu...04467B38>
-> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py(198)execute()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py(199)execute()
-> for data in application_iter:
(Pdb) n
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py(200)execute()
-> write(data)
```

Comment: What's the exact traceback? Put a `pdb` call before `request.get_json()` and see what is it returning.

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: Oh, so the problem was indeed with how I sent the request with curl. Got it, thanks!